# Import Column transformation hangs without any indication what is going on

Tags: sql, ssis, bids, dataflow

**Backstory**
I have recently been given the task of maintaining a SSIS process that a former colleague oversaw. I have only a minimal experience with BIDS/SSIS/"What ever MS marketing wants to call it now" and have an issue which I can't seem to find a solution to.

**Issue**
I have a Data Flow that includes reading images data from a table as well as doing a file read on the images them self's.
For the image read a '`Import Column transformation`' (here by called ICt) is being used, and it hangs indefinitely.

The module gets handed 2500 rows of image data (name, path, date created etc) and using the 'path' column the ICt tries to read the file. I've set the correct input column under '`Input and Output Properties`' as well as setting the output column. The input column has the output columns ID in its `FileDataColumnId`.

When running the process it just hangs as yellow and nothing happens. I can access the images in the explorer, and know they exist (at least some).

**Tools used**

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2008 sp2
- SQL-Server 2012

All hints, tips or possible solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the process log while it's running?  It usually tells you what step it's getting hung up on.

Comment: From the logs I can see the previous component signaling that it has finished processing all of its rows, and the next component (the one that just hangs) turns yellow but does not signal anything in the logs. The pipe between them also shows the, roughly, 2500 rows have been output to the next component.

Comment: Hmm...  What happens if you try to run that same SQL directly on the server?

Comment: Same result when running on the server. I've noticed though that if I have a data viewer on the pipe, that the previous component gets 2409 rows, and then 75 more later. Is there a possibility that this somehow throws the previous component into a loop? Cause it never turns green either. Can I force the data flow to only start work on a component when the previous one has finished?

Comment: I'm not sure.  But if you check the properties, there are settings for how to FORCE execution.  That might be something to look at.  Sorry I don't have many other ideas.